# How to get page load time for all the pages in Selenium WebDriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, page-load-time

I am using page object model like tests,flows,pages.I want to get the page load time for all the pages on console.Time taken to move from one page to the next page.

Could you please provide me the solution.
Thanks in advance

Comment: what all have you tried from your end?

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct method to calculate the time between the 2 pages in selenium.
You will have to wait for a specific webelement to load to get the time for the page load. This is not the most accurate way but it is the only method.

There is a class called as **StopWatch** which can be used to store the time taken for moving from one page to the next page.

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.time.StopWatch; /* import this class */

/* Initializing a StopWatch object */
public StopWatch stopWatch = new StopWatch();

stopWatch.start();    /* starting the clock */
driver.get(url);      /* start point of the page load */

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(by_id_locator));
stopWatch.stop();     /* stopping the clock */

/* Storing the page load time in a string variable */ 
String pageLoadTime  = stopWatch.toString(); 

System.out.println(pageLoadTime);
```